# App review failed due to invalid username and password but its working on all my devices

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, testflight

I uploaded a build to be reviewed by Apple, I provided them with the username: testing@gmail.com and password: 123456. They failed the build saying that the username and password that I provided didn't work but I copied and pasted the username and passwords and it worked on all devices and emulators. They didn't inform me why it failed, whether it was an invalid email and password or the user did not exist. I used the flutter framework and firebase for authentication. Could someone please point me in the right direction to go I am very confused as to what I have to do now?

[image]

Comment: can you login release build ....?

Comment: yea I can, I have tried downloading it through testflight on an iphone with the credentials I provided and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: no screenshots we shared? try using a 'real` email